# Connecting Android app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk/RDS

Tags: android, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing an android app and have successfully integrated AWS services such as cognito, cognito sync and dynamodb. I need a relational database and looking to keep with AWS so i want to integrate RDS with my app. 
However, in terms of networking with android my only experience is connecting to a php/mysql server with Googles volley and so i am not sure how i should be even looking to connect and query to and from the AWS RDS.
I have looked into Elastic Beanstalk but again am not sure if i have to use something like volley to connect to a java tomcat/python web server or use something else?

How should i look at trying to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to connect to RDS like any other remote database you've worked with in the past.

See
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

If you are just looking to host a web service or have server side functions for your mobile App, you might want to consider AWS Lambda or API Gateway which are intended for exactly that.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, i have since been looking at flask and thinking i might build a python web service with it. Do you think this is do able? Or a good idea?

Comment: I'm really only familiar with AWS sorry =/.